# Connect to a running JavaWebStart, Oracle Forms 12c App [Performance Testing]

Tags: oracle, performance-testing, java-web-start, jnlp, oracleforms

Until now I was doing load testing on our Oracle Forms application with Oracle Load Testing. Now we want to change our App, new app will be a Java Web Start application - will be started from a .jnlp file, not from InternetExplorer.

Now, when I'm testing the new app I have got a problem - I can't connect to a running application. I have got a FRM-93618: fatal error reading data from runtime process in the test-tool and FRM-92104 in the running application.
The problem occurs during step nca.connect();

Maybe someone has an idea what can be the problem? 
Or how to test the performance in this kind of application (functional tests are possible - we are using TestComplete).

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific?

1. Exactly which Forms version are you using?
2. What load testing tool are you trying to use? "Oracle Application Test Suite"?? If OATS, which version?
3. Are you doing this as part of E-Business Suite?
4. Are you trying to run from a static JNLP file or are you using the Forms Servlet (dynamic)?
5. Are you aware that custom jar files must be referenced in extensions.jnlp and not as part of the ARCHIVE parameter?